# How can the compareTo method work together with array.sort to sort an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compareto

I know that compareTo can return positive negative and zero values.

So if I use

```
public class x implements Comparable <Object O> {/*...*/}
```

and assign inside

```
public int compareTo(int i) {       
    if (this.intg < i) { return -1; } 
    else if (this.intg > i) { return 1; } 
    else { return 0; }
}
```

Will I be able to use sort `Array.sort(O[]objects)` in this way?

I do not know the connection of `array.sort()` and `compareTo()`.
It even does not call the compare method to sort it.
So what does the `compareTo()` input really do? Where can I pass it if I cannot call this method when I use `array.sort()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Javadocs of [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])):

> Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the array must be mutually comparable (**that is, `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a `ClassCastException` for any elements `e1` and `e2` in the array**).

So the sort method does rely on the `Comparable` interface of the array elements.

Comment: So you mean that the e1 and e2 must be in the same class?

Comment: Yes, or one a subclass of the other.

Comment: @ksdawq Not necessarily. As long as the elements implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @manouti so if they could be different , where can I pass e2 into the compareTo method. When I sort, it will not ask me to call compareTo

Comment: @ksdawq To clarify, elements can be of different types but they have to be _mutually comparable_. For every two elements `e1` and `e2` in the array, `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a class cast exception. Concerning your question, the type parameter of `Comparable` dictates which type the current comparable can be compared to. For example, if your class `X` implements `Comparable<X>`, then an instance of `X` can be compared to another instance of type `X` or a subclass of `X`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Collections.sort` method to do sort-in-place a `List` of your objects. The 2nd argument is your `Comparator` implementation.

Example:

```
List<Animal> animals = .. some ArrayList for example;
Comparator<Animal> comparator = new Comparator<Animal>() {
    public int compare(Animal d1, Animal d2) {
        int v1 = d1.intg;
        int v2 = d2.intg;

        return (v1 > v2 ? 1 : (v1 == v2 ? 0 : -1));
    }
};

Collections.sort(animals, comparator);

// the 'animals' collection is now sorted based on the `intg` property
```

Comment: But I am only allowed to use comparable interface. Can you explain that in comparable interface? Thanks

Comment: The javadocs for Comparable are pretty good, can you explain what you don't understand in them?

Comment: @blm I do not understand how can I pass parameter in compareTo() when it never ask me to call compareTo when I use Array.sort

Comment: First, it's Arrays.sort (I'm assuming. If it really is Array.sort, you'll have to tell us what class that is because it's not a standard Java one). Details matter. Second, you don't call compareTo, Arrays.sort does. It's calling compareTo on one of the objects it's comparing, and passing the other object it's comparing to compareTo. So somewhere in Arrays.sort there's something like e1.compareTo(e2). You need to make your compareTo method return the appropriate value.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you'd be better creating a Comparator rather than implementing Comparable. You can then pass that to the Collections sort method:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
     public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2){
         return Integer.compare(o1.value == o2.value);
     }
});
```

EDIT:

After reading some of the OPs comments, we can demonstrate that the compareTo method is indeed being called:

```
public class TestClass implements Comparable<TestClass> {
    private int value;

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int v){
        this.value = v;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestClass arg) {
        System.out.println("In compareTo");
        return Integer.compare(this.value, arg.value);
    }
}
```

If we then do the following:

```
    ArrayList<TestClass> a = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.setValue(i);
        a.add(t);
    }

    System.out.println("Before sort.");
    Collections.sort(a);
```

We'll see that the compareTo method is being called from within the sort method, as the terminal will show our trace statements:

```
Before sort.
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
In compareTo
```

Comment: Can you explain "you'd be better creating a Comparator rather than implementing Comparable".